# iphone ==> UIAlertView change background?

Tags: iphone, background-image, uialertview

I am trying to change the background of the uialertview.
Everything works fine except the background image i am adding to the uialert view won't scale inside the alertview. So basically you see only part of my background image based on the current size.
Is there any way to make it so that the image scales inside the alerview until it fits?

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [theAlert show];

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.jpg"];
    theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
    CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
    [theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theAlert.frame.size.width, theAlert.frame.size.height)];
    theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    theAlert.layer.contents = (id)[theImage CGImage];
    [theAlert release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please take a look at:
http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert

They explain how to do it by subclassing UIAlertView. Good luck!

Comment: Working great on iOS 6.1 but does not support different interface orientation (alert will be only in portrait mode). I'm talking about this link: http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/03/02/custom-popups-revisited/
If you want to achieve different orientation support - you can subclass `UIViewController`, use same `window` approach just change `[window addSubview:]` method for `window.rootViewController = ...`