# What's the supported way of customizing the UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xamarin.ios

I need to display a UIAlertView to display messages, but I need to change the background colors and textcolors. Is this possible? If so, what is the supported and recommended way of doing so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom UIAlertView iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331396/custom-uialertview-iphone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone ==> UIAlertView change background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410782/iphone-uialertview-change-background)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of those. I specifically tagged iOS5 and if you read the comments the suggested answers don't work with 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *supported* way beside the exposed properties of [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) and its delegate: [`UIAlertViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAlertViewDelegate) (pretty limited).

This is likely the point that the other links (in the comments) wants to make - i.e. the *hacks* that worked in earlier iOS releases do **not** work anymore. You can adapt them - but it's likely to break again. Here's the official words from Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html):

> Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

In reality a lot of applications do subclass `UIAlertView` and the same tricks will also work with MonoTouch (at least as well as they would from Objective-C) but it's **not** supported and it will breaks/need adjustments between iOS releases. I won't recommend it but playing with the hierarchy is likely the only option (beside building your own).